# DB2: how to export data file and own by db2inst1 via ADMIN_CMD

Tags: db2, export, db2-luw

There is some requirement that I need to run the export command in Java via JDBC. Hence below is the command I execute

```
CALL SYSPROC.ADMIN_CMD('EXPORT TO /tmp/header.csv OF DEL SELECT * FROM MYTABLE');
```

However, when I ssh login to the database server via db2inst1, I checked the /tmp/header.csv is own by db2fenc1 user, which not allow me to delete but read-only access as shown below:

```
[db2inst1@26ea60b7e4a1 /]$ ls -lrt /tmp/header.csv 
-rw-r--r-- 1 db2fenc1 db2fadm1 24335 Nov 12 12:25 /tmp/header.csv
```

May I know how to execute ADMIN_CMD as db2inst1? Or any other workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is by design; `ADMIN_CMD` and other fenced routines execute using the fenced user authority in order to protect ("fence") the instance from buggy or malicious code.

Some people set the fenced user to the instance owner ID during the instance creation, which would cause fenced routines to run with the instance owner authority. However, this creates a serious security vulnerability.

It's better to ask your system administrator to allow the instance owner limited `sudo` or `runuser` rights to execute the necessary commands as `db2fenc1`.